# Recommended way of closing files using pathlib module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, with-statement, pathlib

Historically I have always used the following for reading files in `python`:

```py
with open("file", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        # do thing to line
```

Is this still the recommend approach? Are there any drawbacks to using the following:

```py
from pathlib import Path

path = Path("file")
for line in path.open():
    # do thing to line
```

Most of the references I found are using the `with` keyword for opening files for the convenience of not having to explicitly close the file. Is this applicable for the iterator approach here?

[`with open()` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Comment: Well, yes. You’re still missing the file-closing part in the second example. Not sure why there’s a `Path` difference – `with path.open() as f:` would be the equivalent for the first example, or `for line in open("file", "r"):` for the second.

Comment: You should explicitly call `path.close()` in the second example

Comment: The [`Path.open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.open) docs itself uses an example that still uses `with`.

Comment: `3 - 0` - I'll keep using `with ...`

@GinoMempin - Completely missed that in the docs, thank you.

@RishiDev - there is no `path.close()` method as path.open is returning a file object

@Ry- - Is the file not closed by `python` when it is cleared up at the end of the loop? There is not any variable left to call `close()` on?

Comment: It’s not guaranteed by the language. CPython’s refcounting *will* close the file right after the loop, but it’s best to be interoperable with other Python implementations and continue using `with` for that predictable, deterministic close. (Also, I don’t know if a reference hangs around for a bit on CPython if an exception is thrown inside the loop.)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Something that wasn't mentioned yet: if all you wanted to do was read or write some text (or bytes) then you no longer need to use the context manager explicitly when using pathlib:

```
>>> import pathlib
>>> path = pathlib.Path("/tmp/example.txt")
>>> path.write_text("hello world")
11
>>> path.read_text()
'hello world'
>>> path.read_bytes()
b'hello world'
```

Opening a file to iterate lines should still use a with-statement, for all the same reasons as using the context manager with `open`, as [the docs show](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.open):

```
>>> with path.open() as f:
...     for line in f:
...         print(line)
...
hello world
```

Comment: Excellent point, the code for these functions already uses `with self.open` behind the scenes :-)

Comment: Good answer, but I think it's worth adding that both `read_text` and `write_text` are opening and closing the file, i.e. after the function was executed the file is closed. It's not obvious and I had to go read other answers and then docs on `pathlib` to figure that out.

Answer (score 7):

Keep in mind that a `Path` object is for working with filesystem paths. Just like the [built-in library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) of Python, there is an [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) method but no close in a Path object.

The `.close` is in the file handle that is returned by either the built-in [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) or by using the Path object's open method:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> p=Path(some_file)
>>> p
PosixPath('/tmp/file')
```

You can open that Path object either with the built-in open function or the open method in the Path object:

```
>>> fh=open(p)    # open built-in function
>>> fh
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/tmp/file' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
>>> fh.close()

>>> fh=p.open()   # Path open method which aliases to os.open
>>> fh
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/tmp/file' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
>>> fh.close()
```

You can have a look at the source code for [pathlib on Github](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/pathlib.py) as an indication of how the authors of `pathlib` do it in their own code.

What I observe is one of three things.

The most common by far is to use `with`:

```
from pathlib import Path 

p=Path('/tmp/file')

#create a file
with p.open(mode='w') as fi:
    fi.write(f'Insides of: {str(p)}')

# read it back and test open or closed
with p.open(mode='r') as fi:
    print(f'{fi.read()} closed?:{fi.closed}')

# prints 'Insides of: /tmp/file closed?:False'
```

As you likely know, at the end of the `with` block the `__exit__` methods are called. For a file, that means the file is closed. This is the most common approach in the `pathlib` source code.

Second, you can also see in the source that a pathlib object maintains an entry and exit status and a flag of the file being open and closed. The `os.close` functions is not explicitly called however. You can check that status with the `.closed` accessor.

```
fh=p.open()
print(f'{fh.read()} closed?:{fh.closed}')
# prints Insides of: /tmp/file closed?:False    
# fi will only be closed when fi goes out of scope...
# or you could (and should) do fh.close()


with p.open() as fi:
    pass
print(f'closed?:{fi.closed}')   
# fi still in scope but implicitly closed at the end of the with bloc
# prints closed?:True
```

Third, on cPython, files are closed when the file handle goes out of scope. This is not portable or considered 'good practice' to rely on, but commonly it is. There are instances of this in the pathlib source code.

Comment: 'sup @dawg - thank you, this is a really comprehensive answer. I think me throwing references in to `pathlib` there was a bit of a red herring but the answer seems to be that I would be relying on an implementation detail rather than a language feature.

Answer (score 1):

`Pathlib` is object oriented way for manipulating filesystem paths.

Recommended way of opening a file using *pathlib* module would be using context manager:

```py
p = Path("my_file.txt")

with p.open() as f:
    f.readline()
```

This ensures closing the file after it's usage.

---

In both examples you provided, you are not closing a files because you open them **inplace**.

Since `p.open()` returns file object, you can test this by assigning it and checking attribute `closed`  like so:

```py
from pathlib import Path

path = Path("file.txt")

# Open the file pointed by this path and return a file object, as
# the built-in open() function does.
f = path.open()
for line in f:
    # do some stuff

print(f.closed)  # Evaluates to False.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same boat as the poster of this forum. I'll read a forum about this topic and all the answers always seem to lazily boil down to "use the context manager" with no real explanation or depth.

When you read the pathlib documentation however they don't tell you a recommended way but have conflicting examples. They have one example using a contact manager.

```
with p.open() as fi:
... some code ...
```

Then they have multiple examples after that just using the .open() method directly with no context manager and without any close commands. Also unlike the os module there seems to be no .close() method to be found. I assume this means that the object method closes itself when done. If anyone can give an actual definitive answer to whether or not a pathlib Path object will close itself after using .open() I would appreciate it.